How is a Coxeter complex a simplicial complex?
In e.g. the first definition on Wikipedia, a Coxeter complex is given as a quotient of the Tits cone (with 0 removed) by the positive reals. This makes perfect sense as a topological space, but then in applications to Bruhat-Tits buildings it seems that the structure of a simplicial complex is assumed, and different homeomorphic coxeter complexes are distinguished (There seems to even be equality as sets for two dihedral groups in the definition on Wikipedia, while these are distinguished  as different 2n-gons). How does one give the Coxeter complex the structure of a simplicial complex under this definition? Is the notion of quotient here different than the one coming from simply the group action on the space or is there undescribed further data?
